# How should I write my Models in django(This case is a little specific)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, data-structures

I am in a bit of a weird situation right now and hence this question. Say I have a game and I have a website that shows stats for all its players. Now my problem is that I have a bunch of levels and I want to show stats like personal best(least no of moves or time) and stuff for each level to each player on my website. Now if I have to store all this data for each player, how would I do so? Originally I thought why not a table each for a player which has columns of level no, personal best and so on. But, then I would have a 100 tables (or models in this case of django) if I had 100 players and querying for a leaderboard and stuff becomes a problem. So my next best solution I thought was maybe have a table (model) with player names and have as many columns as there are levels and values for each entry would be their personal bests. But, then if I added more levels, scalability becomes an issue and it isn't an elegant solution either.

So this is my problem, it isn't very technically to django or whatever tags I might put. But I feel like there might be someone out there who better knows what problem I am in and can teach me or point me in the direction of an elegant solution.

As always, I greatly appreciate your answers!

Comment: Why would you need a table for each player? You just want a single table with a ForeignKey to player.

Comment: And you don't need columns for each level either. You just need three fields: player, level, score.

Comment: Have a record for each player that contains fields of the data you want to store. This is fundementally a normalised database. A table for each player is anti-pattern.

Comment: Have one generic Model (class) that adequately describes a user.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, I get what you mean, but then I would like the player field to be a primary key, because then I wouldn't have repeating player names unlike in the case of a foreign key and seeing the same names appear for like 25 levels is a bit a messy, especially after you go and view it inside the admin panel.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Also, I already have this system using django signals where when a new user is created, a new player model object is also created, but in case of a ForiegnKey I am not sure how I would do that, knowing that I have a bunch of other values I must set since, I cannot have default values set.

Comment: @hvywhppngcrm please read my comments addressed to DanielRoseman, I think you might get a better understanding of what I am trying to fulfill.